# Why can't Kotlin auto cast generic type

Tags: kotlin

If you are familiar with unity3d, I'm trying to implement a similar pattern for unity components:

```
AddComponent<T>();
GetComponent<T>();
```

So I made this snippet in kotlin:

```
val map = mutableMapOf<Class<Any>,IComponent>()

fun <T : IComponent> addComponent(component : T){
    map.put(component.javaClass,component)
}
fun <T : IComponent> getComponent(klazz : Class<T>): T {
    return map.get(klazz)
}
```

First of all, I have to pass a class to the getComponent method, I can't infer the type from T like C# and I was wondering if there is a way to do this.

And most importantly, why is the method giving me a compile error saying the I'm returning IComponent where T is required, although I did say that T IS an IComponent?

I have to cast to T which is unsafe, this works perfectly fine in C# universe but I'm new to kotlin and I'm wondering if that's possible.

Answer (score 3):

> First of all, I have to pass a class to the getComponent method, I can't infer the type from T like C# and I was wondering if there is a way to do this

To be able do something like this the type have to be [`reified`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters).

In your case it would be something like this:

```
inline fun <reified T : IComponent> getComponent(): T {
    val klazz = T::class.java
    // something-something that returns T
}
```

> and most importantly, why is the method giving me a compile error saying the I'm returning IComponent where T is required, although I did say that T IS an IComponent

You said that the type `T` is `IComponent`, but not that `IComponent` is `T`. And the `map` contains `IComponent` as values. Some of them can be `T`, but there're no guarantee for compiler that they are. So compiler falls with error, and says it isn't sure you will get something of type `T` out of the `map`.

So you need to `force cast` result to the type:

```
return map.get(klazz) as T // in your case you will have to cast klazz to Class<Any>, btw
```

To make it castles you should define `map` as

```
val map = mutableMapOf<Class<*>,IComponent>()
```

instead of

```
val map = mutableMapOf<Class<Any>,IComponent>()
```

---

Also, it would be better to use optional type `T?` for `getComponent`, in pair with conditional cast `as?`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer
the problem with the inline and reified solution is that "getComponent" method is coming from an interface so I can't do inline. And tried to change the map definition to what you suggested, I still need to cast to T, or maybe I miss understand what you mean by castles

Comment: @HassanKhallouf, you can keep original `getComponent`(which takes class as the function parameter) to access all private data, and use inline/reified `getComponent`(it will take class as generic type parameter) wrapped for the better function interface